# Convert from dictionary to dataframe when arrays aren't equal length?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{1: ["a", "b", "c"],
2: ["d", "e", "f", "g"]}
```

that I want to turn into a dataframe like this:

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | f |
| 2 | g |

but when I try use `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()` I get an error because my arrays aren't the same length. How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: provide the sample data with unequal array lengths

Comment: Updated, sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {1: ["a", "b", "c"],
        2: ["d", "e", "f", "g"]}
```

**Code**

```
pd.Series(data).explode()
```

output(series):

```
1    a
1    b
1    c
2    d
2    e
2    f
2    g
dtype: object
```

if you want result to dataframe, use following code:

```
pd.Series(data).explode().reset_index().set_axis(['id', 'item'], axis=1)
```

output(dataframe):

```
    id  item
0   1   a
1   1   b
2   1   c
3   2   d
4   2   e
5   2   f
6   2   g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v,index=[i]*len(v),columns=['items']) for i,v in map1.items()])\
      .rename_axis('id').reset_index()
    
      id items
    0   1     a
    1   1     b
    2   1     c
    3   2     d
    4   2     e
    5   2     f
    6   2     g
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.